# Accessing the value of sibling fields on a react-final-form component

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I have two selection fields on a react-final-form form. The selection field has a list of "options" to present in the dropdown.
What i'd like to do is ensure that the options available in the second dropdown are "reduced" by the items chosen in the first dropdown.

So this requires the second dropdown to know what value was selected in the first dropdown. This is the concept of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
const fruitOptions = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes'];
<Field
  name = "morningTea"
  component = {SelectField}
  label = "Fruit for Morning Tea"
  options = {fruitOptions}
/>
<Field
  name = "afternoonTea"
  component = {SelectField}
  label = "Fruit for Afternoon Tea"
  options = {_.without(fruitOptions, morningTea)}
/>
```

But I can't see a way to get access to other field values on the form. Given that the list of "fruitOptions" is not a field of its own.

Answer (score 8):

OK this seems to me like a documentation issue - I will raise a ticket.

Essentially the documentation is just missing that the [FormRenderProps](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#formrenderprops) type also has a 'values' prop. From here, in the component that is decorated by the react-final-form, you can have access to props.values, and pass the value down to other components/field from there.

E.g.

```
<Form
    render={formRenderProps => {
        const { morningTea } = formRenderProps.values;    
        const fruitOptions = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grapes'];
        <Field
          name = "morningTea"
          component = {SelectField}
          label = "Fruit for Morning Tea"
          options = {fruitOptions}
        />
        <Field
          name = "afternoonTea"
          component = {SelectField}
          label = "Fruit for Afternoon Tea"
          options = {_.without(fruitOptions, morningTea)}
        />
    }}
/>
```

I also created an example of this on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zz168xox0) for anyone that has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you can get the value of the option in the field "morningTea" Assuming the value is stored as  "morningTea.value"

you can pass in the options like this :

```
 <Field
   name = "afternoonTea"
   component = {SelectField}
   label = "Fruit for Afternoon Tea"
   options = {fruitOptions.filter(option => option != morningTea.value)}
 />
```

i Assumed it via this concept :

```
 const q = [1,2,3,4,5]
    console.log(q) = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
const y = q.filter(w => w != 1 )
    console.log(y) = "[2,3,4,5]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately the value of the option in the field "morningTea" is what i was having trouble getting access to - it's not as straightforward as "morningTea.value" so it seems! I think I found the answer anyway... see next comment.